# SQL Server Extended Event Session for Attention is missing field sql_text

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, query-store

I have an extended event session set up to track Attention events, to monitor procedures that timed out. This is the create script:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ApplicationTimeout3] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.attention(
ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.tsql_frame,sqlserver.tsql_stack,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0))))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'D:\ExtendedEvents\ApplicationTimeout3.xel',max_file_size=(100),max_rollover_files=(5))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

The problem is that in the timeouts that I get, I do NOT get the sql_text. (Nor do I get tsql_frame or tsql_stack). It's not returned when I do the "Watch Live Data".

I do SEE the timeouts, they occur at the same time as the ones I see when I query against sys.query_store_runtime_stats (with execution_type_desc = 'Aborted'). However, I get a limited set of fields back, and they're not the ones I need.

Also incidentally, there are many MORE events logged via the Extended Event than what I see when I query sys.query_store_runtime_stats. I have no idea what they are.

Any clues as to how I could actually get the sql that's being executed? I can get the stored procedure name by querying the query store tables. What I'd like to get is the parameters that the stored procedure is called with.

Comment: I'm looking for the full sql text of the stored procedure that's being executed. I can find the stored procedures via query store. I need the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to track query timeouts, I found this Extended Event to be more useful:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [QueryTimeouts] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(SET collect_statement=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([result]=(2))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([result]=(2)))
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
    (SET filename = 'G:\QueryTimeouts.xel', max_file_size = 5, max_rollover_files = 2)
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS)
```

You have it described here:

https://adbsql.blogspot.com/2019/11/tracking-query-timeouts-with-extended.html

Note: that's my own blog post.

I used it few years ago, so I'm not 100% sure, but I think you should get the queries with runtime parameters. I also had problems with the attention event as you describe. It seemed to produce bogus entries. That's why I switched to rpc_completed and sql_batch_completed.

Comment: I think only the statement attribute captures parameters. You may need an event other than rpc_completed to capture stored procedure executions, depending on how they're called. [Extended Events And Stored Procedure Parameter Values](https://www.scarydba.com/2018/09/24/extended-events-and-stored-procedure-parameter-values/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm trying it out.

Comment: Hey, you're awesome! Thank you so much, this works well and is exactly what I needed. The full statement, with parameters, shows up in the Statement field. Previously I had never even heard of the Result = 2 filter.